# Get logged-in asp.net membership user from SQL Server Table Trigger

Tags: sql-server-2005, asp.net-membership, triggers

I want to do some simple data change auditing on an SQL Server table. I have created the trigger as explained in this article http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/pop-rivetts-sql-server-faq-no.5-pop-on-the-audit-trail/

But when a user log's into the ASP.net application  with their asp.net membership account and do a data update, the trigger captures **"NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"** as the name of the user who made the changes to the data. Is there away of getting the logged-in asp.net user name from the trigger instead of this generic **NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are seeing nt authority because that is the identity of the app pool that the worker process is running in.

the only way you will see the actual user is if you use AD authentication and set impersonation true.